# Get values with lookup

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a variable that looks like this

```
variable "drive_map" {   
  type   = map (list(string))
  default = {
    CC-APP-DB    = ["C","D","E","F","G","H","L","M","N","T","U"]
    CC-DB-RPT    = ["C","D","E","F","G","H","L","M","N","T","U"]
    CC-DB-DIST   = ["C","D","E","L","T","U"]
    others       = ["C","D"]
   }  
 }
```

The key is defined in the module by a variable name_space.
How do I do a lookup that will return  the list of the drive letters based on the name_space value

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
lookup(var.drive_map, var.name_space, ["some_default_value"])
```